# Integrate Github commits to gitlab repository

Tags: github, gitlab

Is this a possibility to integrate github repository in gitlab.
My basic need is to commit in github and flow it all in gitlab.
I am not sure if this can be done!
Is this a classical case of CI?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not have a look at the documentation, for example at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do some [mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/) of your project. I guess (but not tested) that if the repository have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, pipelines will be launched when commits are mirrored.